Fluid dynamics (Applications of Bernoulli's equation)
Let's do a thought experiment. Suppose I have an infinite tube of diameter $2d$ placed horizontally, and I put a piston of diameter $d$ in it and filled it with an ideal liquid (i.e., coefficient of viscosity is zero). The piston touches the upper end of the tube. I applied a force on the piston. So what will happen? Is it that the liquid contained in an area of diameter $d$ will move with a certain velocity, and the liquid in the lower half remains at rest? If it is so, then suppose I assumed a cylindrical liquid column whose upper half is in the upper half of the liquid and lower half in the lower half of the liquid. The mass inside the cylindrical tube remains constant with time. I draw a free-body diagram of a cylindrical column. The pressure variation due to height is balanced by the weight of the liquid column, but the pressure variation due to velocity is not balanced, so the COM of the liquid column will have net acceleration upwards. But this is not what happens in reality. Please tell me where I am wrong in my modelling. Here, I have assumed that velocity variation is only between two layers, and velocity remains constant throughout each layer such that there is a discontinuity at the boundary of the two layers.

Could you please explain your question better using a diagram or picture?

Please someone answer the question or provide a good resource so that I will get hints about my particular doubt

Yes, in theory, for an incompressible, ideal fluid (no viscosity), a valid solution is that the piston displaces only a cylinder of fluid while the rest stays at rest. You will notice that if your tube is infinite, the required force is infinite as the kinetic energy of the moving water "core" is infinite.
However, this solution is extremely unstable due to the shear and the flow will mix due to Kelvin-Helmholtz instability. Since the actual flow will be turbulent, it is hopeless to apply Bernoulli. In addition, for real fluids with finite viscosity, you typically need to apply no slip boundary conditions at the face of the pipe, so the solution is not even valid anymore.

Thanks a lot . Your answer is much valuable to me and the community
